# Center a div containing a script

Tags: javascript, html, css, p5.js

I'm trying to center a p5.js script in the middle of a page. I tried wrapping it with a div, and centering that, but it doesn't work

```
 <body>
    <div id="game"><script src="snakegame.js" type="text/javascript"></script></div>

    <div id="score_wrap"><h1 class="score">SCORE: <div id="score"></div></h1></div> 
    <div id="hscore_wrap"><h1 class="score">HI-SCORE: <div id="hiscore"></div></h1></div>     
</body>
```

This is what I tried to do

```
#game {
  width: 900px;
  height: 900px;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.score {
  font-family: "Bungee", sans-serif;
  float: left;
  color: #fff;
}

#score_wrap {
  float: left;
}

#hscore_wrap {
  float: right;
}

body {
  background-color : #1048a3;
}
```

THIS IS INSIDE snakegame.js:

```
var s;
var scl = 20;
var food;
var pkeyCode = '';

// MAIN CODE FOR THE GAME
function setup() {
  frameRate(9);
  createCanvas(600, 600);
  s = new Snake();
  pickLocation();
}

function pickLocation () {
  var cols = floor(width/scl);
  var rows = floor(height/scl);
  food = createVector(floor(random(cols)), floor(random(rows)));
  food.mult(scl);

}

function draw() {
  background(51);
  s.update();
  s.show();
  if(s.eat(food)) {
      s.score += 1;
      if(s.score >= s.hiscore) s.hiscore = s.score;
      pickLocation();  
  }

  fill(255, 40, 100);
  rect(food.x, food.y, scl, scl);
 }

  function keyPressed() {
    if(keyCode === UP_ARROW && pkeyCode != 'DOWN_ARROW'){
        s.dir(0, -1);
        pkeyCode = 'UP_ARROW';
    } else if (keyCode === DOWN_ARROW && pkeyCode != 'UP_ARROW'){
        s.dir(0, 1);
        pkeyCode = 'DOWN_ARROW';
    } else if (keyCode === RIGHT_ARROW && pkeyCode != 'LEFT_ARROW'){
        s.dir(1, 0);
        pkeyCode = 'RIGHT_ARROW';
    } else if (keyCode === LEFT_ARROW && pkeyCode != 'RIGHT_ARROW'){
        s.dir(-1, 0);
      pkeyCode = 'LEFT_ARROW';
    } /* else if (keyCode === ENTER){
        console.log('Cheating');
        s.total++;
        s.score++;
    } */
  }



// FUNCTIONS RELATING TO THE SNAKE, AND SNAKE PARTS ARE DEFINED HERE
function Snake() {
  this.score = 0;
  this.hiscore = 0;
  this.x = 20;
  this.y = 20;
  this.xspeed = 1;
  this.yspeed = 0;
  this.total = 0;
  this.tail = [];

  this.dir = function(x, y) {
      this.xspeed = x;
      this.yspeed = y;
  }

  this.eat = function(pos) {
      var d = dist(this.x, this.y, pos.x, pos.y);
      if(d < 1) {
          this.total++;
          return true;   
      }
      else {
          return false;
      }
  }

  this.dying = function() {
      this.total = 0;
      this.tail = [];
      this.score = 0;
      this.x = scl*3;
      this.y = scl*3;
  }

  this.death = function() {
      for (var i = 0; i < this.tail.length; i++) {
          var pos = this.tail[i];
          var d = dist(this.x, this.y, pos.x, pos.y);
          if (d < 1) {
              this.dying();
          }
    }
    if(this.x >= width || this.y >= height) {
        this.dying();
    } else if (this.x < 0 || this.y < 0) {
        this.dying();
    }
}

this.update = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.tail.length - 1; i++) {
        this.tail[i] = this.tail[i + 1];
    }
    this.tail[this.total - 1] = createVector(this.x, this.y);

    this.x += this.xspeed*scl;
    this.y += this.yspeed*scl;

    s.death();

    this.x = constrain(this.x, 0, width-scl);
    this.y = constrain(this.y, 0, height-scl);

}

this.show = function() {
    fill(200, 255, 200);
    for (var i = 0; i < this.total; i++){
        rect(this.tail[i].x, this.tail[i].y, scl, scl);

    }
    fill(255, 255, 255);
    rect(this.x, this.y, scl, scl);
    document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = this.score;
    document.getElementById("hiscore").innerHTML = this.hiscore;
  }


}
```

Sorry for the awful formatting, I'm new here

Comment: What's in the snakegame.js?

Comment: I think your code should centre your #game div. Is it possible your JavaScript file does not add content to that div, but to another element like the body? You can inspect with the browser developer tools to check that the game content is inside your element.

Comment: @R.Mazarei I edited the main question

Comment: Could you provide a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)? Your script refers to many undefined functions.

Comment: Sorry, can't get the fiddle to work, but here's the [files](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-9TugyOP92VQzg2MFgzbENpbE0) if you want them.

Answer (score 0):

is this what you mean?

I **put a border around** it so you can see it as the **js file is not loaded here**

I also **wrapped the score comments** in a div so that they play nice on wider screens

```css
#game {
  width: 900px;
  height: 900px;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
.scorecontainer {
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto
}
.score {
  font-family: "Bungee", sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
}
#score {
  float: left;
}
#hiscore {
  float: right;
}
body {
  background-color: #1048a3;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="game">
    <script src="snakegame.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </div>
  <div class="scorecontainer score">
    <h1 id="score">SCORE: </h1>
    <h1 id="hiscore">HI-SCORE: </h1>
  </div>
</body>
```